# HTML in Menu title

Tags: routes

I want to be able to add HTML tags in the Menu title - line breaks, italics, etc.  I've gotten as far as needing a custom function in my template.php file.  Something about "theme_menu_link?"

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an issue in Drupal core, and not the Superfish technique or module.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, I guess that you can use Jquery. You can manipulate the html outside the text that you want. See this functions (with examples) to manipulate your html http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential security risk, so be sure to only let trusted users have permissions to do this. You can use the [Menu HTML](http://drupal.org/project/menu_html) module. HTH